# Turn method into recursive

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I want in a ponzi Scheme to see the total number of users i have below me.

This is the hardcoded method that works and i want to make it recursive

```
public int getAllChildrenFromDown(List<Credential> children) {
    if (!(children.size() == 0)) {
        for (Credential child : children) {
            count = count + 1;
            List<Credential> grandChildren = credentialRepository.findByParentId(child.getParentId());
            if (!(grandChildren.size() == 0)) {
                for (Credential grandChild : grandChildren) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    List<Credential> greatGrandChildren = credentialRepository.findByParentId(grandChild.getParentId());
                    if (!(greatGrandChildren.size() == 0)) {
                        for (Credential greatGrandChild : greatGrandChildren) {
                            count = count + 1;
                            List <Credential> greatGreatGrandChildren =credentialRepository.findByParentId(greatGrandChild.getParentId());
                            if(!(greatGreatGrandChildren.size()==0)) {
                                for (Credential greatGreatGr: greatGreatGrandChildren) {
                                    count=count +1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Below is what i tried but i get infinite loop

```
public int getAllChildrenFromDown(List<Credential> children) {

    if (!(children.size() == 0)) {
        for (Credential child : children) {
            count = count + 1;
            List<Credential> grandChildren = credentialRepository.findByParentId(child.getParentId());
            getAllChildrenFromDown(grandChildren);

        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `grandChildren` should probably be `credentialRepository.findByParentId(child.getId());` otherwise you're iterating over the same children infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @doelleri commented above solution is 
**credentialRepository.findByParentId(child.getId());**

instead of 
**credentialRepository.findByParentId(child.getParentId());**